# LessThanOrEqual Date without time

Tags: symfony, validation

I try to validate a Date (not DateTime)

in my validator, i have :

```
myDate:
    - Date: ~
    - LessThanOrEqual:
        value: today
        message: "myDate must be less or equal than today."
```

Before submitting my form, i send this date to my API (i use symfony as an API with FOSRestBundle):

```
myDate:"2017-06-09T00:00:00.000Z"
```

But when i look Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\LessThanOrEqualValidator in this method :

```
protected function compareValues($value1, $value2)
{
    return $value1 <= $value2;
}
```

i have these values:

$value1

```
DateTime::__set_state(array(
   'date' => '2017-06-09 02:00:00.000000',
   'timezone_type' => 3,
   'timezone' => 'Europe/Paris',
))
```

$value2

```
DateTime::__set_state(array(
   'date' => '2017-06-09 00:00:00.000000',
   'timezone_type' => 3,
   'timezone' => 'Europe/Paris',
))
```

And my validation fails.

Can you help me to solve this problem. I don't need time, i just want to validate the Date. How can i remove the 2 hours ?

Thanks

EDIT : 
In my php.ini, i have :

```
date.timezone ="Europe/Paris"
```

I solved the problem by sending the right time

Comment: `2017-06-09 02:00:00` in GMT+2(which is `Europe/Paris`) is `2017-06-09 00:00:00` in GMT (which the `Z` at the end of your client output refers to), so that conversion is correct. Looks like you need to take a look at how you're generating your timestamp on the client side. What's your `date.timezone` setting in php.ini?

Answer (score 0):

First of all `LessThanOrEqual` do just what its names stands for. It compares if left operand is less or equal to the right operand. No matter if it's a  `\DateTime` or `int` or something else.

Since you validating `\DeteTime` i'd suggest you to use [Callback Constraint](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html) or [Expression Constraint](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Expression.html) so you can define how to validate those. My personal choice for this usecase would be the validation via POST_SUBMIT event in you FormType. See - [How to add validators on the fly in Symfony2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9832757/how-to-add-validators-on-the-fly-in-symfony2)